# Parse retrieve columns from 2 different objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I've been using sql forever and i'm now stepping into using parse. I've reach a problem regarding the database structure. i have 2 objects called stores and users. i've added the stores objectId to each user so that i can identify which user is to which store. I do not know if there is another way, but this was what i could think of.

The issue is that i want to retrieve all the users and the store names which is connected to the users. How can achieve this using parse?

My code at the moment.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"users"];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {


        for (PFObject *object in objects) {

        }

        NSLog(@"%@", objects);



    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }

}];
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does sound like the aim is to fetch related objects, but my understanding about how to do that differs from @Dima.  You do it like this...

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"users"];

// this tells the query to eagerly fetch the related store object
[query includeKey:@"store"];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    // handle error, or ...
    for (PFObject *object in objects) {
        // object is from the users table, and object[@"store"] will contain
        // the complete, related store object, eagerly fetched...
        NSLog(@"the store object for %@ is %@", object, object[@"store"]);
    }
}];
```

Comment: This solution definitely sounds better for loading an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just want to fetch a related object? [The documentation covers this](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#top/iOS).

You should be able to fetch a related object like this:

```
PFObject *store = user[@"store"]; // reference to related object but may need to be fetched

[store fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
  // at this point you have fetched the store or you already have it
  NSString *name = store[@"name"];
}];
```

Comment: Looks to me like this will work, but has the disadvantage of needing multiple asynch queries nested in the result block of the main (users) query in order to get the related object.  Parse provides includeKey: on PFQuery to get the related objects on the first pass.

Comment: @danh I didn't know about the `includeKey` method, that is better for sure if that's actually how it works. I'm not familiar with Parse and just posted a working solution I found in the documentation. I'll leave my answer here as an alternate solution for lazy loading a single relation.